# Returning a value from a javascript input prompt box to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor-server-side

I am working on a Blazor server project and have this button in my component

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@GetUserInput">Add Name</button>
```

Here is the code I have that the click event is calling

```
    protected async void GetUserInput()
            {
                var result = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getName");
            }

    function getName() {
        var retVal = prompt("Enter Name : ", "name here");
        return retval;
    }
```

In the javascript function, retVal has a value but in the GetUserInput method,
the code crashes with the error message below

```
    ReferenceError: retval is not defined
        at getActivityName (https://localhost:44318/script.js:15:11)
        at https://localhost:44318/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:70045
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at e.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://localhost:44318/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:70011)
        at https://localhost:44318/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:26293
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at e.invokeClientMethod (https://localhost:44318/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:26263)
        at e.processIncomingData (https://localhost:44318/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:24201)
        at e.connection.onreceive (https://localhost:44318/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:17286)
        at WebSocket.i.onmessage (https://localhost:44318/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:46503)'
```

I am not sure what is going on? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive. retVal, not retval - JS won't complain about "retval" - it's just undefined.

```
function getName() {
        var retVal = prompt("Enter Name : ", "name here");
        return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: Wow.. I can't believe I didn't catch that. Thanks. Works now